# Why printing a string three times gives error 'cannot be intrepreted as an int'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

https://pastebin.com/ztix8Aue

```
 def namex3():
  ask = input("What is your name?")
  name = ask
  for i in range(name):
   print(name * 3)

 namex3()
```

---

I'm trying tob define a function called “namex3” that takes an argument called 
“name” and prints “hello " {name} three times on the screen, however I am getting an error that it `Cannot be interpreted as an integer`, how would I fix this?

Comment: Missing `"` on line 2.

Comment: Unindent on line 5.

Comment: Unindent on line 7.

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` on line 4.

Comment: @user5173426 it's a part of the for loop, so it must be indented.

Comment: `range` needs an `int` argument, and `name` is of type `str`

Comment: Change `range(name)` to `range(3)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments above, fixed:

```
def namex3():
  ask = input("What is your name?")
  for i in range(3):
      print(ask)

namex3()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
What is your name?TFX
TFX
TFX
TFX
```

Comment: That's the one, I guess. You could add `raw_input` if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you intend to use a function :

```
def namex3():
    print(*["hello " + input("What is your name?")]*3, sep = "\n")
namex3()
```

Comment: Upvoted. Dunno why someone downvoted this answer which shows some pythonic possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You could even shorten it to

```
name = "some name"
print(name * 3)
```

Or (with newlines):

```
print("{}\n".format(name) * 3)
```

Comment: Wouldn't that print `mkmkmk` stating `mk` is what user enters.

Comment: @user5173426: Added the newline version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
def namex3()
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    for i in range(3):
        print("Hello", name)

namex3()
```

Notice that every indent level is 4 spaces which is the adviced style in Python.

Answer (score 0):

As OP asked for a function that will print "Hello {name}" three times, here it is:

```
def name_three_times():
    name = input("What is your name?")
    print(f'Hello {name}\n' * 3)
```

Note the use of f-strings: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're attempting `range('hello')`

`range()` expects integer arguments, but you are passing 'hello', which is a string.